Google OAuth2: Custom Nonce Parameter Not Passed Back in Redirect
I'm working on integrating Google OAuth2 into a WordPress plugin and trying to secure the authorization flow using a custom nonce parameter. Here’s what I’ve done:
1. Generated the nonce and added it to the authorization URL using add_query_arg:
nonce = wp_create_nonce('seo_insights_auth_nonce');
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
$authUrl = add_query_arg('nonce', $nonce, $authUrl);

2. Stored the nonce in the WordPress database for validation after the callback:
update_option('seo_insights_auth_nonce', $nonce);

3. Checked the nonce on the callback:
$stored_nonce = get_option('seo_insights_auth_nonce');
$received_nonce = isset($_GET['nonce']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['nonce']) : '';
if (!$stored_nonce || $received_nonce !== $stored_nonce) {
    error_log("Invalid or missing nonce. Stored: $stored_nonce, Received: $received_nonce");
    return;
}

However, after Google redirects back to my plugin, the nonce parameter is missing from the URL. Here’s the authorization URL being generated:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...&nonce=abcdef123456
And here’s the URL received after Google redirects back:
https://my-site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=seo-insights-settings&code=...&scope=... 
What I've Tried :

Ensuring the nonce parameter is properly added to the authorization URL.
Logging and validating the generated nonce on both sides.
Switching to using the state parameter for validation, as suggested in the Google OAuth2 documentation.

My Questions :

Is Google OAuth2 designed to ignore custom parameters like nonce?
If state is the only reliable way to pass custom data, how do I handle both state and nonce securely in this flow?
Any insights or recommendations for handling this issue securely within Google OAuth2 would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Instead of putting this parameter into the Google auth dialog URL, you need to put it into the redirect_uri parameter you are passing.

Whether Google will let you add random parameters to the redirect URI, you'll have to test. Often OAuth providers allow only the use of redirect URIs configured in the app settings, with the state parameter being the only one allowed to have a dynamic, changing value. If that is the case with Google as well - then you'd have to stick your data into that one.

Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my code to include the state parameter as you advised. The issue is that when I am redirected back to my site after successful authentication with Google, the state parameter is missing on subsequent requests, even though it was present during the initial callback.

It should be available the moment you are getting redirected back from Google, to your own app - when the redirect URI that contains the value, gets invoked. Of course it won't be present any more on any subsequent requests - unless you explicitly pass it along somehow.

I reorganized my code to ensure a more structured flow for handling the OAuth process, and I have implemented the state parameter as you suggested. It is now correctly included in the redirect URI from Google. Thank you so much :)
